# Crazy SSIS Component Arrangements

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2005 to not rearrange your SSIS package components when you close and re-open the .dtsx? VS2005 always moves my components around in the Control Flow tab and adjusts the flow pointers to seemingly random positions and it gets quite irritating. Anyone know the setting (if any) to stop this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It must have been something with the install because when I reinstalled 2005 it didn't re-arrange or resize any of my layouts regardless of what components were on the screen (i.e., a dataflow or sequence container).

Answer (score 0):

SSIS doesn't re-arrange my control flows or data flows.

I either do it manually or use the auto-layout, but it never does them without me initiating a move.

The only odd thing it does is its choice of placement of a component during a paste operation.

Comment: Weird...
Mine will alter where the components are placed and sometimes even the size of the box.

Comment: The zoom level DOES affect the behavior of the autosize operation.

Comment: This is true, the zoom level does affect the pointer layout behavior. My problem is that the lines are all over and make weird angles when I close and restart the package.

Comment: I also don't have any problems with SSIS re-arranging my objects.  I've been using SSIS since 2005 with teams of 3-6 users without this kind of problem.

Please note this does not apply to packages downloaded from the msdb database.  These packages always have funky layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread but I don't want to create a duplicate, but I'm getting this now (Mar 2017) on my pretty new installation of VS 2017 with SSDT 2017 on Windows 10.

My team mate first noticed it last week (also a <1m old installation of the same set of apps).

I replicated the problem today on my machine with their project.  We wondered if the layout portion of the dtsx xml was corrupt so removed it and got a regenerated part.  I've watched the XML content, the new positions ARE being saved, but when the package is reopened they're being lost, but *not on all packages* ?!?!

**UPDATE A FEW MINUTES LATER**
The result of continued investigation gave a relative simple workaround.
(1) On the problem .dtsx package do a Copy + Paste you now have MyPackage.dtsx and MyPackage 1.dtsx. SAVE ALL
(2) Delete the original MyPackage.dtsx. SAVE ALL.
(3) Rename the new "MyPackage 1.dtsx" copy back to MyPackage.dtsx name. SAVE ALL.
On opening the newly copied version you'll find the layout you last tried to save WAS remembered after all.

Hope this helps someone else more recent who stumbles across this question.
Whoever down-voted this answer in the 30 minutes while I posted that we were seeing this in a newer version and before my update was a little keen to be harsh.